# Clojure: Perlis vs Protocols/Records [soft, philosophical]

Tags: clojure

### Context:

(A) "It is better to have 100 functions operate on one data structure than 10 functions on 10 data structures." —Alan Perlis

(B) Clojure has defProtocol, defRecord, defType

### Question:

is there some style of programming Clojure that gets the benefits of both?

(B) has the advantage of avoiding type errors.

(A) has the advantage of avoiding duplicate code.

Thanks

PS: I would love to hear constructive criticism on why I'm being downvoted + how to restructure the question to make it productive.

Comment: Any question that merits [soft, philosophical] doesn't belong on SO, hence the downvotes - try http://programmers.stackexchange.com for those sorts of questions.

Comment: There is actually an interesting "hard" question here... see my answer

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how you can co-relate the (A) and (B).

(A) is about having consistency i.e if you use same data structure to represent your data (for ex: a user info stored in a map) across various layers of your application then it would make things consistent. If you use many data structure to represent the same info then you will have to write code to transform the structure from one form to another form and also the various functions which work on different structure will not be composable as they expect different data structure.

(B) This is about the various constructs in Clojure.

`defprotocol` : This is not about data structure rather it is about contract/interface i.e a particular type implements a contract and the type can be used in any context where the consumer function require the passed type to implement a contract. Ex: any type that can have can be printed to console (or other writable string) will implement the print contract/protocol.

`defrecord` : To create maps but with some additional interfaces implemented in a default way.

`deftype`: A low level construct to create types and hence you will have to write a lot of code for this. 99% of time you wont need to use this.

Answer (score 0):

The way to reconcile this is to think "abstractions" rather than "data types". Or to paraphrase Alan Perlis:

> "It is better to have 100 functions operate on one abstraction than
>   10 functions on 10 abstractions."

So the Clojure way is to:

- Define your abstractions in a simple, minimal way (using defprotocol)
- Write functions against this abstraction
- Define concrete types that implement the abstraction using defprotocol, deftype etc. (or use extend-protocol to extend the protocol to existing Java classes if you like)